# Is there a way to center non-string elements in a numpy/array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, center, floor

To print the array indexes on the center i tried numpy.defchararray.center() 
but this only works for strings. So the output is ['-abc-','--a--'] etc..
i want my output to be centered float values

```
arr2 = np.array(list(map(float, input().split())))
print(arr2)
```

> arr2 = [1.2 2.2 5.5 7.1]

```
print(np.char.center(np.floor(arr2), 4))
```

Comment: As you said in the start of your question, that function only works with a string. If all you want to do is output the values, you can just translate them back into strings before using `np.char.center` like so: `np.char.center(list(map(str,np.floor(arr2))), 5)`

Comment: numpy.set_printoptions() worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [169]: alist = [1.2, 2.2, 5.5, 7.1]                                                   
In [170]: arr2 = np.array(alist)                                                         
In [171]: arr2                                                                           
Out[171]: array([1.2, 2.2, 5.5, 7.1])
```

Convert the array to string dtype:

```
In [172]: arr2.astype(str)                                                               
Out[172]: array(['1.2', '2.2', '5.5', '7.1'], dtype='<U32')
In [173]: np.char.center(arr2.astype(str),10, '-')                                       
Out[173]: 
array(['---1.2----', '---2.2----', '---5.5----', '---7.1----'],
      dtype='<U10')
```

For string operations, working with a list and list comprehension is often just as good as array methods.  `np.char` functions just apply string methods to the elements of the array, and aren't any faster.

```
In [174]: [('%.2f'%i).center(10,'-') for i in alist]                                     
Out[174]: ['---1.20---', '---2.20---', '---5.50---', '---7.10---']
```

Iterating on a list is faster than iterating on an array.

The newer `format` method has an centering option:

```
In [175]: ['{:-^10.2f}'.format(i) for i in alist]                                        
Out[175]: ['---1.20---', '---2.20---', '---5.50---', '---7.10---']
```